# Composer cannot update or install PHPUnit/php-code-coverage

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, composer-php

**Problem:**

I'm trying to run `composer update`, but it crashes on trying to install PHPUnit/php-code-coverage. (I'm running update to try and solve a different problem, but that's probably not relevant.)

What seems to be happening is `composer update` starts off fine and tries to update other packages, but whenever it reaches PHPUnit/php-code-coverage it crashes immediately.

Output from the CLI:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 31 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (5.2.4): Loading from cache
```

And then the CLI (php.exe) crashes with error code c0000005.

Composer.json:

```
//...
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "1.23.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.4.1",
    "codeception/codeception": "2.3.6",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/scout": "3.0.x-dev",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "mollie/mollie-api-php": "1.9.*",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^5.6"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},
//...
```

**What I've tried:**

- Changing the PHPUnit version to 7.0 didn't work and gave the same errors.
- `composer self-update` wasn't necessary and didn't solve the issue.
- `composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^6.4` (as suggested in the [official documentation of PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#installation.composer)) updates composer.json and crashes.
- `composer install` tries to reverse a lot of updates and then also crashes on phpunit/php-code-coverage. `composer update` then updates the reverted updates from install again (before crashing).
- deleting the entire vendor folder and reinstalling it also crashed.
- Moving phpunit/phpunit to require instead of require-dev, then running composer update also crashed.
- PHP itself is version 7.1.10, so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: Are you running a VM? I had a problem where Composer would use up all the memory. I had to create a swap to use Composer.

Comment: Nope, I'm not running a VM. Just using Windows.

Comment: Did you try `composer clearcache` and then removing vendor-folder before `composer update -v` ?

Comment: Your issue is more windows/php related than a composer related, can you paste full crash log? Follow these instructions to get it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2722492/vfp-c0000005-errors-and-how-to-troubleshoot-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with the package `phpunit\php-code-coverage`. It's caused by a too long path.

You use `--prefer-source` as workaround:

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

This solution I found also [here](https://medium.com/@tadaspaplauskas/quick-fix-composer-path-length-error-on-windows-d663daa3cae3).

Comment: Friedrich you are a real hero !